# Xubuntu 12.04: replace Thunar with Nautilus in Places plugin

Tags: nautilus, xubuntu, xfce, places

I want to replace Thunar with Nautilus (because Nautilus has internal file search panel and Thunar doesn't)

I've read [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74534/set-nautilus-as-default-file-manager-in-xubuntu) but unfortunately it doesn't work with Places xfce plugin: when I open any folder from Place it still launches Thunar.

Is there a way to launch Nautilus from Places plugin?

Answer (score 1):

I just installed Xubuntu 12.04 and found that if you install Nautilus and then use Docky as a dock or panel, the Docky Bookmarks applet will open your places in Nautilus instead of Thunar.

Answer (score 0):

In menu/settings/preferred applictions (In 12.04) or, I think, in menu/system settings, preferred applications in 12.10+ there is a tab "utilities."
Change the preferred file manager to any in the list you have installed, or type one in (this works for say, Marlin.) 
If you get an error and are using a non-native file manager such as Dolphin (KDE) or Nautilus (Gnome) make sure you have "start gnome services" and/or "start KDE services" in the session and startup part of system settings manager, it's in the advanced tab on the far right. Be aware this WILL launch any Gnome or KDE services marked to start, as well.